# Get IP configuration of virtual or hidden network adapters

Tags: powershell, network-adapter, ipconfig

I need to get IP address of virtual (and/or) hidden network adapters, such as `Hyper-V virtual ethernet` or `Ethernet (Kernel Debugger)`

None of the following commands are giving me what I need:

```
ipconfig /all
Get-NetIPInterface | Select *
Get-NetAdapter | Select *
```

I may have misread the output but it gives only physical address not configured IP address, What options do I have left?

**EDIT:**

Ok I also tried this:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show address
netsh interface ipv6 show address
```

This gives me info for some hidden adapters but not all.

Could be that no other adapters are shown because they don't have IP assigned?

**EDIT2:**

OK, another try is bellow line, but problem is that it won't show loopback and hidden interfaces:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -All -allcompartments -detailed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cmdlet `Get-VMNetworkAdapter` for this task:

```
Get-VMNetworkAdapter -All
```

Will list all Virtual VM network adapters. Use `Get-Help Get-VMNetworkAdapter -Full` to learn more.

Comment: Interesting but  `IPAddress` entry is blank and `Get-VMNetworkAdapter -All | select *` has no `IPAddress` field at all. do you know what could be the cause for this?

Comment: VMs will not get IP addresses until they are booted and connected.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I figured out there is no single cmdlet that will query all possible interfaces for IP address, so I wrote a small script.